# What to do with not used variables when optimising a fitness function?

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I'm optimising a fitness function using a GA. DNN is used to compute the fitness function using 4 input variables. The original data has 8 variables but to optimise DNN accuracy I have dropped 4 variables. Now the best solution exists of only the 4 parameters used. The complete solution should contain 8. The difference in DNN accuracy is significant, the MSE dropped from around 150 to around 20. I can't use all variables. Should I simply ignore the others? Or use some other method? Please let me know if you have any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: it's unlikely that dropping features leads to such an improvement with DNN, you are probably missing something else

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia why not? Those features may be junks. Otherwise, why do we do feature selection?

Comment: You do that with ML models, because they add degrees of freedom... neural network will just ignore them

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I have never heard that a vanilla neural network does this, not without dropout/regularization at least. Please quote your source. Neural network is also ML model.

Comment: Some past posts on this topic: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349155/why-do-neural-networks-need-feature-selection-engineering), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349155/why-do-neural-networks-need-feature-selection-engineering)

Comment: I really struggle to find anything backed by theory/paper/literature online that shows that FS in NN actually improves performance, but ok (btw, you linked the same question twice)